# ASP, Listview conditional Alert

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, listview

I'm currently working with a listview in which I want an htmltablecell to possess the onclick property which is driven by the codebehind rather than a javascript.. However I'm guessing that's pretty much a dream getting it to obey the C# code... Anyways this is what I want it to run:

```
    protected void show_anm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label hiddenc = (Label)listview1.FindControl("hidden");
        Alert.Show(hiddenc.Text);
    }
```

and here's the Alert class

```
public static class Alert
{
    public static void Show(string message)
    {
        string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\'");
        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";

        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

        if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
        {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Alert), "alert", script);
        }
    }
}
```

The point is creating a listview with a two conditional tablecells, one which appears only when a certain condition is met and the other appears every other time (that's alredy sorted out). Where the one demanding a condition is Clickable, and upon clicking it it'll display an Alertbox with Data from a specific DB cell... 
Sorry if my language and the question seemes off, English isn't my native language and I haven't doused myself in Coffe yet.

Any help on the matter would be most appritiated

EDIT1*

```
<asp:Listview ................
    <ItemTemplate>
         <tr ......>
              <td id=default .....>
                    <asp:label ........ Text='<%# eval("stuff") %> />
              </td>
              <td id=conditional onclick=alert()..........>
                    <asp:label ......... Text='<%# eval("stuff") %> />
              </td>
              <td id=hidden visible=false ...........>
                    <asp:label ......... Text='<%#eval("stuff i want in alert") %>' />
              .....
```

```
<script tyupe="text/javascript">
function alert()
{
  var msg = document.getElementById("tried with label id and tablecell id nothing seemingly worked").value;
  alert(msg);
}
</script>
```

I recently made a workaround that shows the data I want to display in the labels tooltip but I'd still prefer the alertbox to work properly as it feels more natural to click something.

Edit2 In case anyone is wondering I used the ItemDataBound event to bind the visibility of cells default and conditional within an if clause to make sure the control exists and the conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused as to why you're doing what you're doing. Why do you want the codebehind to handle an onclick event of a htmltablecell when you are pumping out javascript to show an alert anyway?

Why not just handle the whole logic within Javascript?

A postback from a htmltablcell will also require javascript

Set your tablecell to call a javascript function which would obtain the alert text from the hidden value and display that;

```
        function ShowAlert()
        {
           var message = document.getElementbyId("hidden").value;
           alert.show(message);
        }
```

Comment: I'm so green at webdevelopment grass is envious at my colour, probably should've mentioned that... I've got nothing against javascript and would gladly use a javascript which possess the same functionality, however my searches on have yet to yield any promising results on howto bind the alerttext to the DBpost that I want to display in the warning/alert.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "DBpost". I assumed your alertext was already bound to the HiddenField? Is there a hiddeField for each item in the list?

Comment: ah, by DBpost I mean a database post, or more specifically a database element, which I as you assumed have bound to a hidden field inside the listview...

Comment: i've edited my answer to show you how I think it should work. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for the edit. Still doesn't work though, I'm guessing I've done som references wrong, <br> var msg = document.getElementById("hidden").value; <br> That one is currenty referencing to a tablecell but I've also tried referencing to the asp:label without any success

Comment: can you post more of your code, I want to see your markup as well.